# Capturing HTTP/S traffic for an application that uses libcurl

Tags: c++, windows, curl, libcurl, fiddler

I have a UWP application that uses libcurl to make HTTPS calls to my server, I'm trying to view the traffic using fiddler.

What I've tried:

- Defining [fiddler as a reverse proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/usefiddlerasreverseproxy) and I can at least see traffic from Firefox.
- Setting the `ReverseProxyForPort` Registry key to both `80` and `443`.
- Setting the environment variable `all_proxy` to `localhost:8888` (verified that it was part of the app's environment).

I'm using libcurl 7.61 with OpenSSL as the TLS back-end, it's the version from the [vcpkg repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/curl).

Comment: The whole point of TLS is that the traffic is not decodable or interceptable.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://www.acodersjourney.com/capture-cpp-libcurl-traffic-in-fiddler/

Comment: @AshleyTharp yes but that means I have to hardcode that into the application, I'm looking for something more generic, (e.g with other apps like browsers or apps which use WinInet I can just setup Fiddler to work pretty seamlessly). A predefined could cause issues in the general (non debugging use-case).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But I'm talking about a dev scenario where I have access both to the server and the client. And I first want to capture it and see basic information (decryption is the next step - again assuming I have all the information required, not trying to "break" TLS)

Comment: Doesn't matter. Unless the proxy has the server's certificate, basic laws of physics of our shared universe will prevent the proxy from decrypting the traffic (absent the invention of quantum computers, or a flaw in the TLS implementation). You can certainly capture all the encrypted traffic you want, but it'll be just random gibberish.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have the server's certificate, I am only trying to capture that random gibberish for now

Comment: @Darius using Wireshark would make more sense than Fiddler in this situation

Comment: I would recommend using [SSLKEYLOGFILE](https://ec.haxx.se/tls-sslkeylogfile.html).

Comment: @DanielStenberg AFAIK it's enabled by default only from [version 7.64](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/84fcaa2e7300387e2565d3037bad637f5f6d8372), would you have any idea why libcurl would ignore the `all_proxy` setting ?

Comment: SSLKEYLOGFILE support is enabled by default in libcurl since 7.58.0. libcurl doesn't ignore `all_proxy` unless you set a proxy another way.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thanks, I defined `SSLKEYLOGFILE` environment variable but nothing happened, no file was created (I was running procmon the whole time and verified that the process does have this environment variable available)

Comment: @DanielStenberg FWIW after defining the environment variable chrome started to dump the appropriate data to the file defined by `SSLKEYLOGFILE` but the app that uses libcurl didn't.